# how to use initialize method inside a method?

Tags: java

So I have this code. I need to use initialize when switchToView method is called. I don't know how, when it is in a method itself. I have tried, but I only get red under marks.

```
@FXML
public void switchToLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@FXML
public void switchToNewUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NewUser.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}



@FXML
public void switchToView(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    responseFromLogin.LoginToView( loginEmail, loginPassword);
    loginResponse.setText(responseFromLogin.getResponse());
    if (loginResponse.getText().equals("Successfull login")) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        /*
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
            barChartChooser(null);
            Subjects.setUpSubjects();
        }
        */
        stage.show();
    }   
}
```

Comment: you can call initialize() within siwtchToView instead of declaring method withing method

Comment: I don't get it. You mean like this?

Comment: @Override
   initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    barChartChooser(null);
    Subjects.setUpSubjects();
   }
   stage.show();

Comment: Could you send code suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

calling initialize from switchToView

```
@FXML
public void switchToView(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    responseFromLogin.LoginToView( loginEmail, loginPassword);
    loginResponse.setText(responseFromLogin.getResponse());
    if (loginResponse.getText().equals("Successfull login")) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
       // call initialize
       initialize();
        stage.show();
    }   
}

 
        @Override
        public void initialize() {
            barChartChooser(null);
            Subjects.setUpSubjects();
        }
```

Comment: hi, I am getting that url & arg cannot be resolved to variable

Comment: you can remove url and arg , just call linitialize();  as initialize method doesn't need those arguments

Comment: I am getting this, when I remove url and arg.

Comment: The method initialize(URL, ResourceBundle) in the type MainController is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: edited above answer, removed argument from initialize method

Comment: It is telling me to remove the override. I need it to set up the program